# I want to write a macro which will delete all rows containing date older than X days for a column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a Excel sheet which has N rows and M Columns out of which one of the column has Date values. Based on the value in this column I would want to delete all the rows having date older than X days.

Can I get any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Using Formula. Just subtract the 2 dates (example screenshot below) and then filter the 'difference' column based on your requirements and delete the unwanted data.
   [image: Date Difference using Excel Formula]

   .
   2.Another is to use VBA which will be much more dynamic.

   ```
   Sub Delete_Rows_based_on_Date()

   Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer, iNum As Integer
   Dim iLoopR As Integer, iLoopC As Integer
   'Benchmark Days
   iNum = 7

   iRow = Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   iCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


   For iLoopR = 1 To iRow   'Assuming data starts from Row #1
       For iLoopC = 1 To iCol   'Assuming data starts from Col #1 (A)
           If IsDate(Cells(iLoopR, iLoopC)) Then ' Check if the cells contains a Date Value
               If DateDiff("d", Now(), Cells(iLoopR, iLoopC)) > iNum Then
                   Cells(iLoopR, iLoopC).EntireRow.Delete
               End If
           End If
       Next iLoopC
   Next iLoopR
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub deldat()
dim ws as worksheet
dim lrow as variant
dim lcol as variant
dim dt as variant
dim n as variant

n=7 'assuming 7days to delete records

set ws=thisworkbook.sheets(1)
lrow=ws.range("A1:A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row 'Getting Last Row
lcol=ws.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Getting Last column
set dt=date() 'getting current date

for i=1 to lrow
cell=ws.cells(i,1) 'Assuming date values in column 1 Or A
if datediff("d",dt,cell.value) > n then
ws.row(i).entirerow.delete
end if
next i
end sub
```

I am not sure of the code. I haven't tested it. Try the code and get back with the shortcomings or error in this code